# Программа,которая создает случайным образом перестановку и считает количество циклов в ней

Tags: java

Необходимо создать программу, которая принимает в качестве параметра размер перестановки, создает случайным образом перестановку и считает количество циклов в ней. Вывод программы – количество и состав циклов.
Пока удалось написать генерацию случайной перестановки.
Совершенно не могу понять, как считать в ней количество циклов.

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  int index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
  int swap = array[index];
  array[index] = array[i];
  array[i] = swap;
}
```

Comment: Уточните требования задачи.

Comment: Это все условия задачи, что даны. Остальное-на свое усмотрение.

Comment: Вот эти условия не понятны. Вы не понимаете что такое перестановка, а также количество и состав циклов. Приведите пример, что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Изначальный массив: 1 2 3 4. Его перестановка: 3124. Количество циклов:2. Состав циклов: (123) (4)

Comment: что значит размер перестрановки?

Comment: количество чисел

Comment: вы имеете ввиду, что цифра (4) осталась на своем месте? а если ее в одном цикле переместили на новое место, а уже в другом - вернули назад? что тогда должно быть?

Comment: Мы не учитываем, каким образом осуществлялась перестановка программой. Если бы мы самостоятельно осуществляли эту перестановку, то мы бы посчитала то, что 4 осталась на своем месте, как один цикл.